# Generate QR code with google API in PHP with data sent from Form?

Tags: php, jquery

This is functions.php file:

```
<?php
    include 'QR_BarCode.php';
    function url(){
        $qr = new QR_BarCode();
        $qr->url('here i want data sent from form');
        $qr->qrCode();  
    }
?>
```

This is my html form index.php. I want the generated QR-code on index.php page.

```
<form method="post" id="form_id" action="functions.php">
    <input type="tel" name="number">
    <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub">
</form>
```

[Here is the link I generate qr codes from.](http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-qr-code-generator-class.htm/)

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to run your function. Right now it's declared, but you do nothing with it.

Here is an example how it could be done:

```
<?php
include 'QR_BarCode.php';

function url($number, $sub){

    if(empty($number) || empty($sub)) {
        die('Error. Fields cannot be empty');
    }

    $qr = new QR_BarCode();
    $qr->url();
    $qr->qrCode();  
}

// This is only example. You should validate those inputs.
url($_POST['number'], $_POST['sub']);
```

Remember though, that running functions.php without `$_POST` data will result in PHP Notice. You can make a check for `$_POST` values in request and only then run this function

```
if(isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    url($_POST['number'], $_POST['sub']);
}
```

Comment: While this approach of @jdrzejb is more accurate, we really can't figure out, what `$qr->qrCode();` does. And also, `url($_POST['number'], $_POST['sub']);` just checks if the parameters are empty or not. This function does nothing more. Where to use `$_POST` parameters is still vague. So this answer should be improved.

Comment: Also, SUPERGLOBALs are already available in the function scope, so there is no reason to pass them in via function arguments.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/20S80